# convert image to string with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I'm converting an image to a string with the following code. The conversion works when I include some debugger statements. It stops working when I remove them. 
Here's a link to my github [github link](https://github.com/benhalverson/smithsAngularDemo)
What am I missing here?

```
export class ImageUploaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  @ViewChild('mycanvas') mycanvas;
  preview(e: any): void {
    const canvas = this.mycanvas.nativeElement;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

    // show image to canvas
     const render = new FileReader();
    render.onload = (event: any) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;
          context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      };
      img.src = event.target.result;
    };
    render.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    this.convertBufToStr(render.result);
    localStorage.setItem('imageStore', render.result);
  }
   convertBufToStr(buf): string {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
  }

  convertStrToBuf(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2);
    const bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
      bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
  }
  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: Where did you set the debug points to get the example to work? Also, without them, which part of the code stops working? is it only the string conversion?

Comment: @nipuna777 I added a debugger statement after localStorage.setItem... and in the convertBufToStr function before the return statement. Without the debug points, the value of imageStore is an empty string

Answer (score 1):

The `readAsDataURL` method is asynchronous. When you call `localStorage.setItem('imageStore', render.result)`, the results are not yet populated. This is why adding debug points solves your issue.

What you can do is to listen the load event of the file reader.

```
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    this.convertBufToStr(render.result);
    localStorage.setItem('imageStore', render.result)
}, false);
```

You can read more about this API and how it can be used in the MDN article here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL