# How to convert image to string in angular

Tags: html, angular, database, base64

I am using angular 7 and need to upload image and send it to server to put it in database. So i wondering how to convert image into string and latter back in image so i can display it in app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396524/convert-image-to-string-with-angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert image to string with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396524/convert-image-to-string-with-angular)

Answer (score 0):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150397/1440240) explains how to convert an image into base64 encoded data.

> You can use the HTML5  for it:
>
> Create a canvas, load your image into it and then use toDataURL() to
>   get the base64 representation (actually, it's a data: URL but it
>   contains the base64-encoded image).

I don't think that's how you want to save your images though. Continue researching perhaps.